# Strange behaviour with sheet.getLastRow()

Tags: google-apps-script

I do have a spreadsheet with 2 headlines I would like to sort. For this to work I used to have this code, which was working:

```
var AbrechnungsDatei = SpreadsheetApp.openById(DeletionList[i]["DateiID"]);
var Abrechnungsblatt = AbrechnungsDatei.setActiveSheet(AbrechnungsDatei.getSheets()[0]);

var DataRange = Abrechnungsblatt.getRange(this.StartRowAbrechnungsblatt, 1, AbrechnungsDatei.getLastRow(), AbrechnungsDatei.getLastColumn());
DataRange.sort(this.AB_ColumnDatum);
```

This worked until a few months ago. Now to get it working I have to subtract 1 for the last row (AbrechnungsDatei.getLastRow()-1). Otherwise I get a service error when I try to do something with this DataRange.
What seems very strange to me is that this problem does not occur with the columns, although it is the exact same situation.

Can you give my a hint for this? Is there a better way for doing the same? I do know that there is a function to get the entire sheet as a range (getDataRange). I do however not want to include the header lines.

Thanks for your help.

Best regards

Heinz

Comment: What is `StartRowAbrechnungsblatt`?   Is it a named range?  You are using it with the `this` keyword:  `this.StartRowAbrechnungsblatt`.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `getLastRow()` method on a Spreadsheet object.

```
AbrechnungsDatei.getLastRow()
```

`AbrechnungsDatei` is a Spreadsheet, not a Sheet tab.

Even though the `getLastRow()` method is available to a Spreadsheet object, I would never use it on a Spreadsheet object.  I'd only use the `getLastRow()` method on a Sheet object.

```
Abrechnungsblatt.getLastRow()
```

I'm going to change `Abrechnungsblatt` to `sh` as an abbreviation for sheet.

Currently:

```
var DataRange = Abrechnungsblatt.getRange(this.StartRowAbrechnungsblatt, 1, AbrechnungsDatei.getLastRow(), AbrechnungsDatei.getLastColumn());
```

Would change it to:

```
var DataRange = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow(), sh.getLastColumn());
```

If you don't want to include the header lines, and the header lines are always the same rows, then you can set the start row in the `getRange()` method to one row beyond the header rows:

```
getRange(start Row, start Column, Number of Rows, Number of Columns)
```

You *should* subtract the number of header rows from the length of rows in the spreadsheet.  `sh.getLastRow() - number of header rows`.  Otherwise you may have blank data at the end of the array.